# The requested URL was not found on this server. Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, error, installation, 404

Home Page after fresh Installation :

[image: home]

Admin Page :

[image: admin page]

I followed this [link on Stack](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89125/how-to-fix-magento-2-2-0-0-rc-admin-page-not-found-after-installation)

```
maddy@maddy:/var/www/html/Magento2$  ls -a -l
total 916
drwxrwx--- 12 maddy www-data   4096 Sep 30 17:57 .
drwxrwxrwx  4 root  root       4096 Sep 30 17:59 ..
drwxrwx---  4 maddy www-data   4096 May 30 15:39 app
drwxrwx---  2 maddy www-data   4096 May 30 15:39 bin
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data 435065 May 30 15:39 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data   1843 May 30 15:37 composer.json
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data 344683 May 30 15:39 composer.lock
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data   3381 May 30 15:39 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data    631 May 30 15:39 COPYING.txt
drwxrwx---  5 maddy www-data   4096 May 30 15:39 dev
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data   1116 May 30 15:37 .gitignore
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data   2864 May 30 15:39 Gruntfile.js.sample
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data   6355 Sep 30 18:22 .htaccess
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data   9314 May 30 15:39 .htaccess.sample
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data   1368 May 30 15:39 index.php
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data    315 May 30 15:39 ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
drwxrwx---  4 maddy www-data   4096 May 30 15:39 lib
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data  10376 May 30 15:39 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data  10364 May 30 15:39 LICENSE.txt
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data   5071 May 30 15:39 nginx.conf.sample
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data   1427 May 30 15:39 package.json.sample
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data   1627 May 30 15:39 .php_cs
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data    814 May 30 15:39 php.ini.sample
drwxrwx---  2 maddy www-data   4096 May 30 15:39 phpserver
drwxrwx---  6 maddy www-data   4096 May 30 15:39 pub
drwxrwx---  7 maddy www-data   4096 May 30 15:39 setup
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data    884 May 30 15:39 .travis.yml
drwxrwx---  7 maddy www-data   4096 May 30 15:37 update
-rw-rw----  1 maddy www-data    101 May 30 15:39 .user.ini
drwxrwx---  7 maddy www-data   4096 Sep 30 18:17 var
drwxrwx--- 29 maddy www-data   4096 May 30 15:39 vendor
```

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

if is use below changes it gives `Internal Server Error`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

</Directory>


maddy@maddy:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-09-18T15:09:02
```

Comment: [enabled `mod_rewrite` ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache)

Comment: HOW TO check this ?

Comment: follow the hyperlink..

Comment: those chages gives me 500 Internal server error.

Comment: you need to restart apache after making changes.. and these changes need to be done before magento installation.

Comment: i restart it after making changes

Comment: I need to install again.

Comment: yes, need to reinstall.
before reinstalling , you need to put exact link of your magento root directory instead of `/var/www/` in `<Directory /var/www/>`

Comment: ok , am i making changes `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` at correct path UBUNTU 16.04

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66467/discussion-between-saurabh-ranjan-and-kashish).

Answer (score -2):

I did the following steps and that solved the problem for me:

1. `cd /var/www/html/magento`
2. `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
3. `sudo  php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
4. `sudo service apache2 restart`

if this way not solved your problem you can try this

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

sudo rm -rf var/cache/*

sudo rm -rf var/generation/*
```

sudo a2enmod rewrite

:)