# Magento2.3: I am getting 404 admin error after installation

Tags: magento2.3, installation

I am getting 404 error after installation and frontend is working fine.

[image]

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: This error generating in local machine or server

Comment: On local machine

Comment: Are setting up fresh magento setup or any other setup have to install

Comment: Fresh magento2.3.3

Comment: Please check in magento root directory have .htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Magento 2 2.0.0-RC Admin page not found after installation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89125/how-to-fix-magento-2-2-0-0-rc-admin-page-not-found-after-installation)

Comment: Did you changed any thing in .htaccess file ? in Default Magento .htaccess ?

Comment: No I haven't changed anything in new magento .htaccess

Comment: Can you please try to run your admin with index.php ? e.g. www.example.com/index.php/admin ?

Comment: Front end is working

Comment: Admin is not working.. Not Found
The requested URL /admin_14vbl3/ was not found on this server.

Comment: You're getting 404 error in your frontend if you will add any wrong URL key there ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100732/discussion-between-shiwani-and-kishan-savaliya).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your url rewrite module is enabled in your system.

if not run following command.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Comment: "Module rewrite already enabled" after running this command getting this message

Comment: check .htaccess is available in magento root directory or not

Comment: .htaccess is available in root

Answer (score 0):

This has always worked for me.. very simple

## 1. move the .htaccess from pub folder to root

## 2. wipe cache