# Magento2: I need to override the footer in my custom module

Tags: magento2, overrides, footer

I have checked the best solution. But not able to override the footer for my custom module.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: You're using default Luma theme for you frontend ? Which section you want to override please attach that here with screenshot.

Comment: Actually I need to add my custom jquery in footer. So that it will render on all CMS page

Comment: You're using any custom theme ?

Comment: No, I am not using custom theme. I need to override in my custom extension

Comment: Okay you have any specific section which you want to override then can you please attach that in question with screenshot ?

Comment: I don't have a section but need to add jquery in footer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100699/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-shiwani).

Comment: @Shiwani you can edit by move layout/template file to your theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `default.xml` file in your custom module here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_jquery" after="-" template="Vendor_Module::custom_jquery.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now you need to create one template file here on this path in your custom module.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/custom_jquery.phtml

Content for this file is..

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
(function  () {    
    require(["jquery"], function($) {
        $(document).ready(function($) {
            /*You can add your custom jQuery code here*/
            alert("Hello");
        }); 
    });
})();
</script>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Can you please check this?https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294189/magento2-3-i-am-getting-404-admin-error-after-installation/294190?noredirect=1#comment422991_294190

Comment: Okay let me check

Answer (score 0):

Instead of override footer you can add your custom block into **footer-container**
`default.xml``

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_block-jquery" template="Vendor_ModuleName::html/customBlock.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And add jquery content inside your phtml template or you can directly load jquery into `default.xml` file on header.

Anything you will place into `default.xml` will load on all pages.