# Admin Url not found (404) and css-js not working while migrating magento 2.3.3 local to server

Tags: magento2, server-setup, js-css, admin-url

Hey there here i am trying to migrate my magento 2.3.3 localhost to the server 
i have changed Database user,database name in env.php and also  i have updated core_config_data in Database.
But still i am facing two issues 
1.Front end without CSS and JS.
[image]
2.Admin Url Not found
[image]
hence my env.php url is also correct.
Does anyone have any solution for this.

Comment: Check URL for missing CSS in browser console. Also do you use  https?

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89125/how-to-fix-magento-2-2-0-0-rc-admin-page-not-found-after-installation