# Changed Base_Url and Now I am getting 404

Tags: magento2, url, migration

I just migrated a Magento2 site from a cloud server to my localhost to do some developer work on.  I have everything I need installed and ready to go.  I am just trying to redirect the Base-URls.  I have already went into the command line and redirected both base and secure urls like this.

`php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://localhost/upperlimitsinc/"`

After changing the url I checked PHPMyAdmin and it shows that it has changed but when I go to the site url I get a 404 and not from Magento. Everything is running on MAMP.

404 ERROR: The requested URL /upperlimitsinc/ was not found on this server.

Comment: you try reindex command

Comment: Ok I figured this out. I need to change my URL to url="http://localhost/httpd/" file path.  I have the Store working now.  However, for admin panel I do not have working. I am getting localhost refuses to connect.

Comment: what's error show in admin panel?

Comment: This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: check this link - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/magento-2-admin-url-not-working-and-loaded-frontend-is-all-messy

Comment: That Solution did not work.  I am not sure why I can access everything but the admin panel.  I get the same thing local host refuses to connect. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: Also, When I go to store Login I get this.  The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after spending so much time trying to figure this out. This is what I did.

1. Changed the url to the correct file path.  `http://localhost/httpdocs/`
2. Went to phpMy Admin and changed `core_config_data` table configIDS: 1. rewrites, 5.frontend and 6.adminhtml to `0`.
3. run `php/bin magento setup:upgrade`
4. run `php/bin magento setup:dicompile`
5. Delete all folders under `pub/static`
   Delete `var/cache`
   Delete `var/composer_home`
   Delete `var/generation`
   Delete `var/page_cache`
   Delete `var/view_preprocesse`
6. run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy.`

And that worked.

Answer (score 2):

After update your base url from your local, you need to run: php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 1):

use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Maybe this link help you feather - [How to fix Magento 2 2.0.0-RC Admin page not found after installation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89125/how-to-fix-magento-2-2-0-0-rc-admin-page-not-found-after-installation) and https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-404-error-page-not-found-admin-url-magento-2/

Thanks