# URGENT: I changed the primary domain for the Main store and now the Admin panel does not load at all (I get a 404)

Tags: multidomain

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
```

We were running Magento 1.9.4 with 3 domains on [www.domainOLDMagentoinstall.com](http://www.domainOLDMagentoinstall.com):

```
www.domain1.com
www.domain2.com
www.domain3.com
```

We set up a new Magento 2.4.2-p1 on [www.domainNEWMagentoinstall.com](http://www.domainNEWMagentoinstall.com). I wanted to switch the first domain from old 1.9 Magento to the new today so I have done the following:

- In the new Admin panel of Magento 2 ([www.domainNEWMagentoinstall.com/admin](http://www.domainNEWMagentoinstall.com/admin)) **I changed the base URL for Main store from https://www.domainNEWMagentoinstall.com TO https://www.domain1.com**
- removed domain1.com from 'Domains' in Cpanel of the [www.domainOLDMagentoinstall.com](http://www.domainOLDMagentoinstall.com) hosting account
- added domain1.com to 'Domains' in cPanel of the domainNEWMagentoinstall.com hosting account

Now [www.domain1.com](http://www.domain1.com) loads correctly the new Magento 2.4.2-p1 site (from the domainNEWMagentoinstall.com Magento install) but **there is no way to access the Admin panel as both of the following:**

domainNEWMagentoinstall.com/admin

and

domain1.com/admin

**resolve to an Error 404 page.**

*How can this be fixed?*

---

UPDATED on October 9th, 2021:

I tried to run the following:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

But it did not help.

I guess my problem is similar to this as my front page is broken as well:

[Changed Base_Url and Now I am getting 404](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319162/changed-base-url-and-now-i-am-getting-404)

I also deleted all the folders mentioned in that article. The only thing I was not able to do was the 'dicompile' command as it could not be found.

When I go to my phpMyAdmin and look for core_config_data - I changed:

```
   web/unsecure/base_url
    web/unsecure/base_url
```

Here is another article but I don't think I have a wamp server:

[magento 2 admin url not working and loaded frontend is all messy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91087/magento-2-admin-url-not-working-and-loaded-frontend-is-all-messy)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally get this fixed:

**Step 1**:

Connect to your database via phpMyAdmin, sort the rows by the ***Value*** heading and look for starting with http...

**Step 2**: Change the incorrect URL(s) to the right one(s) on all the lines.

**Step 3**: Run the following commands via SSH:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```